# Compile web form and retrive a file with mechanize

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I need to extract all the files in this website in an automated manner: http://www.coeweb.istat.it/predefinite/tutto_paese_merce.asp?livello=ATE07_AT2&riga=MERCE&territorio=S&AG=S

In this website there is a web form with combobox and checkbox to set up and a button to perform the download a xls file.

I find that mechanize is a good python library that can help me in automating this task.
I can configure the combobox to open the results page in html but i dont' undestand how to download the xls file. any advice?

thanks a lot!

```
#my code
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
page = br.open("http://www.coeweb.istat.it/predefinite/tutto_paese_merce.asp?livello=ATE07_AT2&riga=MERCE&territorio=S&AG=S")

br.select_form(nr=0)
control_xls = br.form.find_control("XLS")
br.find_control("XLS").items[0].selected=True
control = br.form.find_control("CODTERRITORIO")    
control.items[0]
print control.value
print control
#select Florence
control.value = ["309048"]
print control
br[control.name] = ["309048"]
response = br.submit()

out_file = open("dataset.html", "w")
out_file.write(response.read())
out_file.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem for me it seems the code is working?

Comment: I need to download also the xls file, but I don't know how do it. (for now I'm able to extract table from the html with pandas, but i like to learn to avoid this trick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the extension of the file you are writing from .html to .xls.

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.coeweb.istat.it/predefinite/tutto_paese_merce.asp?livello=ATE07_AT2&riga=MERCE&territorio=S&AG=S")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.find_control("XLS").items[0].selected = True
br.find_control("CODTERRITORIO").value = ["309048"]
response = br.submit()

with open("dataset.xls", "w") as xls_file:
    xls_file.write(response.read())
```